# Creating a view that consist column with static info

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I' m creating a view like this

```
CREATE VIEW TEST  AS 
    (
    SELECT a.ID, a.E_ID, b.CAT1 AS C1, c.CAT1 AS C2
    FROM RECP a
    JOIN ART  b on (a.ID=b.SKU)
    JOIN ART  c on (E_ID=c.SKU)
    )
```

It works fine but I need to add two additional columns (add1, add2) with static info. It is equal for each row.

For example,

```
ID E_ID  C1  C2  add1 add2
1   10   a   c   NL   RS
2   20   b   b   NL   RS
3   30   c   a   NL   RS
4   40   d   d   NL   RS
```

It does not consist in other tables and equal for every row. How can these  columns add1 and add2 can be addedinto a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS 
(
    SELECT a.ID, a.E_ID, b.CAT1 as C1, c.CAT1 as C2, 'NL' AS add1, 'RS' AS add2
    FROM RECP a
    JOIN ART  b on (a.ID=b.SKU)
    JOIN ART  c on (E_ID=c.SKU)
)
```